# Upgrade TYPO3 version 7.6

Tags: typo3, upgrade, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to upgrade my TYPO3 version 7.6.10 and I guess I should use the Upgrade Wizard in the Installation Tool. But I get the errors:

*/typo3_src should be a link, but it does not exist
Links cannot be fixed by this system*

Path /index.php is not a link
The target /index.php should be a link, but is of type file. This cannot be fixed automatically. Please investigate.

Path /typo3 is not a link
The target /typo3 should be a link, but is of type dir. This cannot be fixed automatically. Please investigate.

My folder structure is like this

httpd.www

- fileadmin

  typo3

  typo3conf

  typo3temp

  uploads

  vendor

  .htaccess

  index.php

So I guess my folder structure is not correct. My question is: Is there a problem in changing the folder structure in such a way, that I create a folder /typo3_src and move /typo3 and index.php to that folder and create the missing symbolic links?  Or is there a smarter way to upgrade?

Comment: Please, add errors inside the question, not as an image

Comment: What do you mean by "This cannot be fixed automatically. Please investigate."? What operating system are you running on?

Answer (score 0):

I always make symlinks in console, like:

```
ln -s ../typo3_src-x.x.x typo3_src
ln -s typo3_src/index.php index.php
ln -s typo3_src/typo3 typo3
```

Where your folder typo3 and vendor and index.php file are in a separate folder, the source folder. You can upgrade or downgrade easier when you do this, and only have to change 1 of the 3 symlinks also. When you change version number.

Maybe it is also for security resons to put the source in a higher up in root folder?

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

- Not necessary to use the upgrade wizard for release updates, e.g. 7.6.**10** to 7.6.**11** (unless release notes tell you so).
- Folder structure should be with symbolic links (as already described by Rustyjim). Also see [Installation Guide: Installing on a unix server](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html#installing-on-a-unix-server) or [Installation Guide: Installing on a windows server](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html#installing-on-a-windows-server)
- If you do it this way, for a release update you basically only need to replace the symbolic link (e.g. rm typo3_src;ln -s ../typo3_src-7.6.11 typo3_src) and clear cache in install tool
- You may want to look at composer installation to use in the future: [Install TYPO3 via composer](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html)
- For major updates, it is a good idea to follow [upgrade instructions](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InstallationGuide/Upgrade/Index.html)
- As a general rule: Always read release notes before updating and test update on a test server (ideally a replica of your production system)